# PrimeNG Calendar Buttons and Default Values Misbehaving

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a pretty basic use case of the `p-calendar` component from [PrimeNg](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/calendar), but many of the buttons on it stopped working recently and I can't figure out why. Here's the HTML and a gif of the behavior:

```html
<p-calendar
  appendTo="body"
  formControlName="birthday"
  styleClass="w-full"
  inputStyleClass="form-control"
  placeholder="Birthday"
  [maxDate]="maxDate"
  [defaultDate]="maxDate"
></p-calendar>
```

[image: gif of datepicker buttons not working]

I understand why the forward button isn't working, but the month/year/back buttons should work but don't do anything. When I implemented this a couple weeks ago, it was working just fine. Then I went on vacation and got back to this. I'm not sure even what to check. There are no errors in the console, and nothing to point me in the right direction.

On a related note, pre populating the field with a value doesn't seem to make any effect on the input. The value stays blank.

There's obviously something going on, but I don't know what to check. Any ideas on what to check or what could be causing this issue?

Comment: I figured out the default date not displaying part. I needed to convert the date string to a date object and once I did that it started showing the starting date.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help from Twitter, we found out that the issue was that `maxDate` and `defaultDate` were set using getters, and that apparently causes an issue with the p-calendar component. Instead of using getters, I initiated the values with `new Date()` and then set the value to what I actually wanted in `ngOnInit`.

```
public maxDate = new Date();
public defaultDate = new Date();


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.maxDate = this.determineMaxDate();
  this.defaultDate = this.determineDefaultDate();
}
```

Comment: I somehow committed the same error twice on the same project. The reason is I went back to getters because I needed the maxDate and defaultDate to update based on some of the other inputs. So I just threw that into ngOnChanges instead of getters and ngOnInit.